# Get value from previous method

Tags: ios, objective-c

im newbie at Objective C, and i have a dumb question about get the return value from a previous method, for example, there is an excercise about converting Celsious into Fahrenheit temperature.
Here is my code:

```
    -(float) getTemperature
   {
    return arc4random() % 40 + (float)arc4random() /(float);
   }

    -(float) converter
   {
    ...
   }
```

The getTempature method is return to Celsious temperature, but is there any way to get the value from this method and apply it into "converter" method?. Im still new at Obj-C, so still confusing in some cases.

Thank you guys very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
-(float) converter
{
    float yourValue = [self getTemperature];
    // do something with yourValue here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do `float temperature = [self getTemperature];`

Answer (score -2):

```
-(float) converter:(float)temperature
{
return temperature + 1;
}
```

call:

```
float result = [self converter:[self getTemperature]];
```

Comment: You are changing the question by adding a method parameter without explaining why the user would benefit from this.

Comment: yes, as for me, it's the best decision in this case

Comment: @Igor The OP isn't after the best solution for you they are after the best solution for them. If you are changing something like that then you need to be adding detail for why it is better.

Comment: It's just my proposition how to pass pass parameter to the method, and I think - it's much better than using global variables or calling "getTemperature" method from "converter". At least for proposed solution,  converter should not generate values itself, it should use concrete value.

Comment: Well you should add that to your answer then as that would be a valid reason for doing it the way you have and wouldn't result in down votes.

Comment: As for me, it's a simple idea and it should be clear from the code